# Entity Framework Core 7 connection certificate trust exception

Tags: ssl, entity-framework-core, connection-string, ef-core-7.0

I recently upgraded to Entity Framework Core 7 in development and I'm getting an exception, "A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.)"  I am using Microsoft SQL Server Developer (64-bit).  I have tried to make changes in the VS2022 Server Explorer to disable encryption and to trust the server certificate, I don't have one installed, but the exception remains.  How can this be mitigated in development?

Answer (score 84):

it is not a bug in EF Core 7.0, instead it is improved security. Microsoft suggest following 3 solution, which ever applies to you.

1. install a valid certificate.
2. Add TrustServerCertificate=True to the connectionstring
3. Add `Encrypt=False` to the connectionstring

**Old behavior**
SqlClient connection strings use Encrypt=False by default. This allows connections on development machines where the local server does not have a valid certificate.

**New behavior**
SqlClient connection strings use Encrypt=True by default. This means that:

The server must be configured with a valid certificate
The client must trust this certificate
If these conditions are not met, then a SqlException will be thrown. For example:

A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/breaking-changes

Comment: "DefaultConnection": "server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;database=db;trusted_connection=true;encrypt=false"      Adding encrypt=false solved the problem. THANKS!

Comment: behind the scenes: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring?view=sqlclient-dotnet-standard-5.1
You will see: Encrypt
- 'true' in 4.0 and above
- 'false' in 3.x and below

Answer (score 30):

Same problem here after upgrading `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` to `7.0.0`

I fixed that by adding `TrustServerCertificate=Yes` to the SQL Server connection string.

Comment: So glad I ran across this. Thank you for posting. Solved my connecting issue.

Answer (score 1):

**The Below code worked for .net core 6 & 7**

```
> "ConnectionStrings": {
>     "SqlServer": "Data Source=DESKTOP-*****;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True;TrustServerCertificate=Yes",
> "LocalSqlProviderEnable": true   }
```

Comment: This adds nothing to the highest voted answer which is the only answer that has decent and comprehensive explanation.

Answer (score -1):

I think it's fails because is a recent update.
I had the same problem and I fixed it re installing the previous version (6.0.11).
I hope this comment helps you.

Comment: I did the same thing, so I could keep working.  I guess I'll have to wait for an EF Core 7 update..

Comment: This is not an error, and the update will not fix this, you should update to the version 7, and disable the encryption please take a look on my answer bellow.

Answer (score -1):

It seems the answer is to await an update to EF Core 7.  This should be a bug.  My development is all on one machine with a SQL Server Development Edition instance. I suppose using localdb might be an approach.

Comment: I have two solutions running against the same SQL Server database.  One is an ASP.NET Core 7 solution that uses EF Core 7 without an problem. Is uses a connection string in User Secrets.  The other is a .NET Core 7 Console application that uses EF Core Power Tools to reverse engineer the database.  This version has the certificate chain error in connecting to the database.  I rolled it back to EF Core 6.0.11 to get it to work.  I don't know what the issue is between the two solutions, but I include it here for the record.  Perhaps someone can enlighten me on what is going on.

Comment: It's not a bug. It's not even an EF issue.

Answer (score -2):

After adding Encrypt=False in the connection string it resolved the issue.

```
"DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=CommunicationDB;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Encrypt=False;"
```

Comment: Please don't affirm answers by repeating them. This was already said in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74577373/861716). Vote for helpful answers instead.